# Replacing a diode-OR gate by a circuit that behaves the same way (also in the presence of feedback loops) without accumulating voltage loss

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Consider the following circuit with two OR gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkNmWP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and the Time Simulation: 
[image]
The OR gates with both inputs 0 generate 0, and after one input is set to 1, 
they remain with 1 as long as there is current. The circuit has memory.

Now consider the implementation of OR with diodes (let's call them diode-ORs):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNGZRk.png)</sup>

and the Time Simulation: 
[image]
In this case, the diode-ORs always generate a 0 whenever both inputs are 0.
The circuit has no memory.
And there is a loss of voltage, that would accumulate if more diode-OR gates were cascaded.

**My question is the following: is there another implementation that behaves like diode-ORs
(i.e., without memory even in the presence of feedback loops)
but does not have a cumulative voltage loss (or has only a very small voltage loss)?**

**Or put another way: can we replace each of the two diode-ORs by a circuit so that the whole system behaves the same way, except that there is no cumulative voltage loss (or the voltage loss is very small)?**

**Maybe using pass transistor logic?** (https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/Digital-CMOS-Design/Pass-Transistor-Logic/OR-gate-using-pass-transistor-logic/)

Dave Tweed suggested to use a "better diode" and that is a correct answer to the question. Is there any other alternative? A problem with that solution is that it cannot be used for the AND case, which I would also like to handle in that way (with low voltage drop, and without memory even in the presence of fededback loops) because diode-ANDs have memory when there is positive feedback (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_logic#/media/File:Diode_AND2_Ideal_Diode.jpg).

I am a computer scientist and I am interested in the answer mainly for theoretical reasons and for teaching purposes. 
I know that the feedback loop is not needed to generate the outputs of the circuit.

Thank you!

Comment: The positive feedback loop **is** the memory. Refer to AoE chapter on Comparators and Hysteresis. Also consider that the OR gate has high-impedance inputs, whereas the diode does not. Use a proper source resistance model instead of ideal voltage sources and you will see how your question is flawed. The ideal voltage source masks the fact that the diode-OR steals power from its input, while OR gates do not. This is why OR gates are capable of supporting a positive feedback loop, creating a memory cell. The memory is *not* inherent in the gate implementation as you seem to suggest.

Comment: Thanks MarkU. I will check the reference. I get what you say, but I don't understand why the question is flawed. A possible answer would be: "yes, just try with a diode which has an infimal voltage loss". I know there are no such diodes, but the fact that this answer would be valid if such a diode existed shows that the question is not flawed (although I can understand that from your perspective it may look as irrelevant or uninteresting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is the following: is there another OR implementation that behaves like diode-ORs (i.e., without memory even in the presence of feedback loops) but does not have a cumulative voltage loss?

This is logically impossible.

The expected behavior of an OR gate is:

- When either input is held HIGH for a sufficient amount of time, the output will be brought HIGH and remain HIGH until after both inputs cease to be HIGH.
- When both inputs are held LOW for a sufficient amount of time, the output will be brought LOW and remain LOW until after at least one input ceases to be LOW.

An OR gate is also required to produce a relatively strong signal (for example, a HIGH output must be greater than 4 V and a LOW output must be less than 1 V) and to accept a relatively weak signal (for example, any input greater than 3 V must be recognized as HIGH and any input less than 2 V must be recognized as LOW)

So, suppose that we have an OR gate (*any* OR gate) whose inputs are A and B, and whose output is C. Suppose, also, that C is connected to B. We then bring A HIGH for a while, causing C to be brought HIGH as well. Then:

- C must remain HIGH until after A and B have both ceased to be HIGH (by the definition of an OR gate).
- B will remain HIGH as long as C remains HIGH, because they're connected to each other.

From the above, we can see that the output of this OR gate will remain HIGH forevermore.

In response to your comment:

> Maybe I have used the name OR gate incorrectly, but then just delete the word OR from the question and then there is no logical inconsistency any more: is there another implementation that behaves like diode-ORs (i.e., without memory even in the presence of feedback loops) but does not have a cumulative voltage loss?

Sure, absolutely. Take an OR gate and then alter it by adding a timer which forces its output LOW once every ten seconds. Then this resulting OR-like device does not have memory in the presence of feedback loops, and it doesn't have a cumulative voltage loss, either. But I don't know whether or not this implementation meets your expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer! Maybe I have used the name OR gate incorrectly, but then just delete the word OR from the question and then there is no logical inconsistency any more:  is there another implementation that behaves like diode-ORs (i.e., without memory even in the presence of feedback loops) but does not have a cumulative voltage loss?

Comment: @Javier I've edited my answer to suggest an implementation. Does the implementation I suggested meet your expectations?

Comment: Thanks again, Tanner. Unfortunately not, because that is not the behavior of the diode-OR. The diode-OR does not have its output LOW every ten seconds. Put another way: the Time Simulation picture for that implementation would be different than the second one above for the diode-OR.

Comment: @Javier What, *specifically*, is not satisfactory about my suggested solution? You say it's not satisfactory "because that is not the behavior of the diode-OR", implying that in order to be satisfactory, a solution must behave like the diode-OR. But you also say that you want something that does not have a cumulative voltage loss, implying that in order to be satisfactory, a solution must *not* behave like the diode-OR. It's impossible to satisfy both requirements at once, so I must be misunderstanding one requirement or the other.

Comment: Sorry Tanner, I should have written as in the post: the solution should behave like diode-ORs (i.e., without memory even in the presence of feedback loops) but does not have a cumulative voltage loss. Or at least that loss should be as small as possible. In your solution there is no cumulative loss, but the rest does not remain the same, or similar. (Anyway, thanks for trying to help, I see this is not been easy for all you, and I appreciate you are making this effort).

Answer (score 5):

Consider your diode circuit: when the inputs are both zero volts, where would the energy come from to maintain an output at anything other than zero volts?

The "real" or "traditional" OR gates have an implicit supply voltage that will maintain the state of the outputs. Simulation tools sometimes "handwave" this away so as to not clutter up the schematic with unnecessary supply connections.

Consider the following circuit diagram representing a traditional CMOS OR gate implemented with transistors:
[image]

In this circuit, the circuit elements that comprise the OR gate are powered from VDD, and thus can provide power to the output Q. In your diode circuit, there is no such power supply, and thus no latching, or as you put it, memory.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Brendan, but I do not get what is your answer to the question (maybe I am missing something...)

Comment: Javier, traditional OR gates do not transfer energy directly from the inputs to the output, instead that energy comes from a separate power supply rail. In a Diode-OR, energy must come from the input to power the output. When your input goes to zero volts, so must the output.

Comment: Thanks, Brendan. I understand that. I want to have exactly the behavior you described of the Diode-OR, but without that much voltage loss: is that possible? 
I thought maybe some pass transistor logic (https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/Digital-CMOS-Design/Pass-Transistor-Logic/OR-gate-using-pass-transistor-logic/) could do that, given that in this case there is no sepparate power supply.

Comment: There are potentially a million answers to your question. Can you use a diode without a voltage drop? No. You could use a Schottky diode and reduce the diode drop maybe. Depending on what you are driving downstream, perhaps resistors in series with your inputs could work. Or a traditional OR gate. If you don’t want a latching behavior, I’m not really sure why you introduced the cross coupled circuit in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any feedback in your second circuit. D3 and D4 are simply cross-connected between the two outputs. When both inputs are high, both outputs are one diode drop below the input voltage, but if either input is low, the corresponding output is two diode drops below  the other input. If both inputs are low, both outputs are low, because there's no other voltage source.

The problem with the diode circuit is that it is completely passive. It has no gain, and therefore no positive feedback. The circuit with real gates has gain, and therefore the positive feedback that creates memory.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Actually, for me the diode circuit has no problem (except for the voltage loss). I know this is the opposite to the way logic gates operate, but I *do want* the circuit to have no positive feedback. My question is: is there other implementation of OR gates that behaves like the diode one (i.e., without positive feedback) but has no voltage loss? Maybe with pass transistor logic?

Comment: Yes. A single OR gate behaves in exactly the way you desire.

Comment: I know that, but that does not answer the question. I do not want to arrange the OR gates differently. I want to implement them differently.

Comment: Your requirements cannot be met.  This arrangement automatically has a positive feedback loop which is all you need to create a memory cell with with SET or RESET inputs. So if you want define your logic table needed, someone can help you. If you just want to amplify the diode output or to Vcc use a comparator

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist: Thanks! I get that is what happens with the usual OR gates. However, this is not the case with diode-OR (as I call them): with them the positive feedback loop does not create a memory. All I want to know is if it is possible to replace each diode-OR by another circuit that has no voltage loss but has a similar behavior (i.e., the positive feedback loops do not create memory cells). This may sound strange to you, but I do research in non classical logics, and somehow there is a connection to this specific question

Comment: As Dave pointed out, all active logic has voltage gain. Even though all semiconductors are considered "active parts" in his case the lowly diode has no voltage gain so it behaves like a passive switch you play with the same ideas with relays. Perhaps our synapses have a memory-less OR SET-RESET logic but I forget.  Maybe that's only for old age. (lol) But the whole point of that logic is to have memory. Otherwise it fails the truth table

Comment: Haha :) Then maybe all I need is some passive logic: is there such a thing? (remember I want this more for theory, not for engineering) 

And I don't know if this completely misses the point, but there I go: isn't pass transistor logic (https://www.electronics-tutorial.net/Digital-CMOS-Design/Pass-Transistor-Logic/OR-gate-using-pass-transistor-logic/) also passive? Could that do the trick I am aiming for?

Comment: You still haven't told us **exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish**. You keep saying "logic with feedback but no memory", which is basically nonsense in the binary logic we're all used to. If you're inventing a new form of logic, you have to lay out the ground rules for us -- we can't possibly guess what you have in mind.

Comment: I want to accomplish this: a circuit C such that if I replace in the first diagram OR1 with a copy of C, and OR2 with another copy of C, the output is the same as that of the circuit with diodes (so that whenever both inputs are low, the output is also low) but with a smaller or nonexistent voltage drop (and for example, when both inputs are high, the outputs are much closer to 5V)

Comment: If all you need is a "better diode", those are readily available. Search for "ideal diode" (used for power switching) or "precision rectifier" (used for signals). These are two approaches for reducing \$V_f\$ to arbitrarily low levels (but NOT zero!).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dave, that was helpful! And google did a good job. I also want to have a similar implementation of AND (with low voltage drop, and without memory even in the presence of positive feedback) but in this cases the classical diode-AND (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_logic#/media/File:Diode_AND2_Ideal_Diode.jpg) does not work (it has memory with feedback loops). Could you think of another solution that does not consist of a "better diode"? Thanks!

Comment: There's no problem with cross-coupled diode-AND gates. Just turn all of the diodes around and tie the load resistors to +V instead of Gnd. It works just as well as the diode-OR case. If either input is low, both outputs are low; if both inputs are high, both outputs are high. I still don't understand why this is better than a single AND gate.

Comment: There's a problem for this case because diode-ANDs have memory when there is positive feedback, contrary to diode-ORs, who do not have memory when there is positive feedback. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: You're wrong, as described in my previous comment. If both inputs are high, there is no possible path by which an output could be held low.

Comment: Dave, what you say is consistent with the fact that diode-ANDs have memory when there are feedback loops. This is also the case for normal AND gates: if both inputs are high, output will always be high, and they have memory. I want AND gates without memory, and diode-ANDs do have memory.

Comment: Perhaps your definition of "memory" is different from mine. How can your diode-AND gates "remember" a 0?

Comment: No, I think I was just confused about this. The problem with diode-ANDs is not that they remember. The problem (for me) with diode-ANDs is that when two of them are cross-coupled and the two inputs are high, then the outputs are always 1. In this case, the feedback loop is self supported, and I do not want this. Note that this is also not the case for normal ANDs. So then the question remains: is there an alternative answer?

Comment: I think I'm done here, because you seem to be talking in circles. The diode-AND outputs are both high *because they don't have feedback*. The normal AND gates have memory (one output is low) *because they do have feedback*. Which way do you want it?

Comment: I understand, Dave. I'll do a last try then. Consider a "real" circuit with input wires a, b and c, and output wires w1, w2 and w3, defined by: (w1 = a * w3), (w2 = b * w1), and (w3 = c + w2). Inputs a and b are always 1.  Now (1) c is initially 0, then w1 = w2 = w3 = 0. Then (2) setting c to 1, we have w1 = w2 = w3 = 1. Afterwards (3) setting c back to 0, w1 = w2 = w3 = 1. They remain with value 1. The circuit has memory. If instead of the OR we use a diode-OR, the result is the same. The circuit also has memory.

Comment: If instead of the "real" ANDs we use diode-ANDs, then in (1), (2) and (3) we get w1 = w2 = w3 = 1. What I would like to have is in (1) w1 = w2 = w3 = 0, in (2) w1 = w2 = w3 = 1, and in (3) w1 = w2 = w3 = 0. Using ideal diode-ORs works for me when there are no ANDs, but with ANDs I get again in trouble. Thank you anyway, I appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 0):

A logic gate **amplifies the input signal**. If you feed back the non-inverted output signal into the input, the output *overrides* a weak input signal and thus, the circuit has a memory.

Consider a similar schematic, only consisting of an amplifier with positive feedback. The resistor is placed so you don't "short circuit" input and output. In a logic gate, these are internal parts that separate the multiple inputs

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBQqOu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit has memory. If you connect the input to +V, the output goes to +V, and through the feedback loop, it stays at +V if you let the input float again. And the same for -V. (The switch voltage is set by the amplifier - input connected to GND.)

So, the answer to your question is simple.

- You cannot have amplification, positive feedback and no memory at the same time.

Because that's a by-product of amplification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I get your point. And what about the option without amplification, but with positive feedback and no memory? That is what I am aiming for in the question. I think you can say the diode-OR (with all its problems) does exactly that: no amplification, and no memory even with positive feedback. If we agree on this, then all I am asking for is a circuit that behaves like that diode-OR but has no voltage low. Is this possible?

Comment: How do you achieve that? All non-linearity in nature comes with an entropy side effect. If you want to go without any voltage loss, you certainly need amplification.

Comment: If you are only after a practical implementation, simply place the amplifying stage outside of the feedback loop. Such "gates" aren't cascadeable, though.

Comment: That's a good point, Janka! Then let's say that I want to minimize the voltage loss, while having no memory even with positive feedback.

Sorry for not being precise formulating the question.

I am interested in this more from a theoretical perspective. It may be interesting for some research I do in non classical logics.

Comment: You have to go linear. An OR gate can be represented as a sum, too. This is achieveable with resistors, as it's just Kirchhoff's node law you employ. Then minimize the currents and you have almost no voltage loss. Or, drop the voltages at all and use current sources and currents for the logic. This all means your energy losses are taken from the logic mesh into your sources and output amplifiers.

Comment: @Javier Would you be satisfied with a circuit that behaves just like your diode-OR circuit except that it has a *very small* voltage drop, perhaps a billionth of a volt?

Comment: (Because if so, I have your answer: yes, it's possible.)

Comment: @Tanner: yes, I would be satisfied, as long as the circuit is used to replace each of the OR gates one by one and not the whole circuit (I know the last option can be simply done by placing a unique OR without feedback loops). In other words, I want a circuit C such that if I replace in the first diagram OR1 with a copy of C, and OR2 with another copy of C, the whole circuit behaves like the diode-OR circuit except that it has a very small voltage drop.

Comment: @Janka: That sounds interesting. Could you show how would that be done for this simple example? Or give me a link from where I could start on my own? Thanks!

Comment: Use current sources instead of voltage sources. Feed all input currents into a node. Put one output "tap" at that node. You now have a cascadeable "SUM" gate without internal amplification. The losses are located in the current sources.

Comment: That sounds great! Just two more questions: what is to put one output tap at that node? and, can this be extended to handle AND gates, perhaps implementing them as a kind of "MIN" gate?

Comment: That "output tap" is just another connection which leaks all the input current into the detector (or another node). And no, you cannot build MIN/AND gates this way.

Comment: And there is also no way to represent the AND as the product of the signals, or as their SUM minus the basic current, or something like that...

Comment: My sum example was deliberately chosen, because it's what your diode example is if you removed the nonlinearity.